# Please help identify this shell casing

Tags: world-war-one, identification, artillery

We found the end of a shell casing in our garden. We believe it is made of brass it’s 3.2 inches across and has the following stamps on it:
DCP oo
75 M
No 32
1917 BA  with N on its side above.

Interestingly it also has flowers engraved on the sides

Any info would be much appreciated,[image: Two images of shell casing; one from bottom, one from side showing flowers.]

The garden is in Grantham, lincolnshire, UK. The house was built approx 1840s, We don't know much about previous owners, but intend to find out, to see if there is a link, which would be nice.

Comment: Welcome to SOe. Some context info about the item could help. I realize that for a finding maybe there will be not much, but it can help (country in which your garden is, what do you know about previous owners...)

Comment: Hi, thank you, the garden is in Grantham, lincolnshire, UK. The house was built approx 1840s, we dont know much about previous owners, but intend to find out, to see if there is a link, which would be nice.

Comment: @Andria, I've moved your comment into the question. The question should contain everything you know about the object; feel free to update further as you discover more.

Comment: A web site [here](https://ator1149.home.xs4all.nl/wfm/ww1/ammunition2.html) has a table which indicated this shell may have been made by *Dominion Copper Products Company (DCP Co)*, out of Canada.

Comment: The primer looks like the one from 7.5 cm Gebirgskanone M.15 (Skoda). It's quite possible there was some cross-licensing of the design though. The gun was widely used "on both sides" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skoda_75_mm_Model_15

Comment: I'm going to guess that the flower engravings are not OEM.

Comment: Flower engravings are a form of [Trench Art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trench_art).